# Browser not opening when LaunchUriAsync is true

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to have the default web browser open up an URL that is provided by the user in this case let's say it's https://stackoverflow.com/ but when the program runs the app is returning true for the LaunchUriAsync, but it isn't opening the browser and navigating to the site. How would I get a browser to open up the URL?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url = StoreUrl.Text;

            Uri uri = new Uri(@"" + url);
            DefaultLaunch(uri);
        }
    async void DefaultLaunch(Uri uri)
        {
            // Launch the URI
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

            if (success)
            {
                // URI launched
            }
            else
            {
                // URI launch failed
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact way how you create and pass the uri to `LaunchUriAsync`? What thread are you calling this method from? There are a lot of remarks on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_). Do any of these apply to you?

Comment: @FlyingFoX I have edited my post to include how I'm passing the uri to `LaunchUriAsync`. As far as the documentation goes I have not found a reason why it would be returning true but not be opening up a new browser or at least a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new project and pasted the following code into the Loaded event

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/"));
```

It worked fine for me.

If the call returns true, there seemingly nothing to stop this from working. At this stage I would suggest this is an environmental issue, or something do with  the shell mechanism of that browser.

From here I would

- Test this in a new clean project.
- Change the default browser, if this works then there is likely some sort of setting/corruption within the browser
- Disable your antivirus and see if it works.

Comment: Just to also share this information. You have to close down the default browser that you are using before it will open up a browser. It will not create a new browser window or a new tab.