# Open URL in Edge from desktop app in Store distributed app?

Tags: windows, winapi, wininet

In the distant past you could open a URL in the browser like:

```
int rc = ShellExecute(hwndMain,"open","iexplore.exe",URL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

However, if you want to distribute your app in the Microsoft Store `ShellExecute` is not allowed any more.

Is there a trusted way to open a (help page) link in the user's Edge browser?

Comment: If Store deployment does indeed require that you not call `ShellExecute`, you can [launch the default app for a URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app) instead. This allows you to launch the default browser or Microsoft Edge in case they are not the same.

Comment: Even if that worked in the past it was never correct. Respect the users configuration and use the default browser instead of forcing IE!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @IInspectable! However, the code snippet is C#, I seem not to be able to find a C or C++ equivalent. Also, see this answer, where the C# version will not create a new tab if the browser is already open.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365360/browser-not-opening-when-launchuriasync-is-true

Comment: If you click on the link to the [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync) you'll see C++ code, provided that you select the appropriate language from the language dropdown at the top right.